# Creating image of Solar System, with intersecting orbits that need to be accurately rotated. I am new to Blender

Tags: import, transforms, image

I have 2d images for the orbits and nodes (lines if intersection) as separate planes. I need to import the images and then put each orbit (plane) intersecting at the correct angle at a specific position.
For example: two planet orbits and a nodal axis (3 image planes). The orbits are set but need to be inclined on the nodal axis (Arrow head and tail).

[image: You are looking from the top. Inner circle is x axis, Outer circle is also x axis but needs to be tilted along the line of the green arrow.]

Comment: hello, do you have some images? it may help to understand

Comment: “2D images for the orbits as separate planes” does not clearly identify what data is in the images. Are they cross-sections of the orbit on the Z axis? Overhead shots of the planet’s in timelapse? More precision, please.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather that point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.